# Git de-selects a commit be default in interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I run git interactive rebase on a branch git for some reason decides that I don't want the `9df79` commit below:

[image]

How is that possible?

I have NOT commented out that line/commit myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Empty" commits are dropped by default (see the comment on line 25 in your pasted-in image), via this bit of code in the setup for an interactive rebase:

```
git rev-list $merges_option --pretty=oneline --reverse --left-right --topo-order \
        $revisions ${restrict_revision+^$restrict_revision} | \
        sed -n "s/^>//p" |
while read -r sha1 rest
do

        if test -z "$keep_empty" && is_empty_commit $sha1 && ! is_merge_commit $sha1
        then
                comment_out="$comment_char "
        else
                comment_out=
        fi
```

The `$keep_empty` variable is set based on the `--keep-empty` (or `-k`) flag you supply on the command line, so without it non-empty non-merge commits come out as `# pick ...`.

(An "empty" commit is one whose source tree is identical to its parent's.)

Comment: Actually, it is line 25, which confused me a little. But nice answer!

Comment: @ThomasJacob: Oops, typo.